Anchor CLI idl convert inside project: unrecognized subcommand
The anchor idl convert command doesn't seem to work when inside an existing Anchor project, and shows the wrong anchor version (0.29.0) in the error message when a path is provided. Example:
➜ anchor --version                      
anchor-cli 0.30.1
➜ anchor idl convert some_idl.json      
error: unrecognized subcommand 'convert'

Usage: anchor-0.29.0 idl [OPTIONS] <COMMAND>

For more information, try '--help'.
➜ anchor idl convert --help                                   
Convert legacy IDLs (pre Anchor 0.30) to the new IDL spec

Usage: anchor-0.30.1 idl convert [OPTIONS] <PATH>

Arguments:
  <PATH>  Path to the IDL file

Options:
  -o, --out <OUT>                   Output file for the IDL (stdout if not specified)
      --provider.cluster <CLUSTER>  Cluster override
      --provider.wallet <WALLET>    Wallet override
  -h, --help                        Print help

I am using avm and have run avm use 0.30.1 prior to this, but also have 0.29.0 installed, and of course this workspace uses 0.29.0.

Move the json file outside of your project to some other folder (e.g. home, desktop, etc). Now you can open a terminal and use the command with the preferred Anchor version.
Also note that you may need to add metadata if the idl doesn't already have it. E.g.
{
  "metadata": {"address": "Some_Pubkey"},
  "version": "0.1.0",

